# Kannel can accept SMPP connection

Tags: smpp, kannel

I have kannel and I can connect to others SMPP servers and send SMS, but can I make my Kannel accept incoming SMPP Conncetion?

Is there anything I must add it to the /etc/kannel/kannel.conf or there is a package must be installed?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

You can use `OpenSMPPBox`. `OpenSMPPBox` is a special Kannel box that listens for `smpp` connections and accepts and sends sms messages from and to `smpp` clients.

`OpenSMPPBox` behaves similar to other Kannel boxes and share a compatible
configuration file format and command line options.

There is a [github repo](https://github.com/pruiz/kannel-opensmppbox).
You can find its whole [documentation here](http://www.smsfoxbox.it/documents/pdf/open_smpp_box_user_guide.pdf)

Comment: I suggest using the version of opensmppbox that's included with kannel (it's in the addons directory of kannel source code.) The github repo could drift away with time and be incompatible with the installed kannel version

Comment: Is there Ubuntu repository for this? as I checked its age is more than 5 years. how I can get the updates?

Comment: Is there GUI for kannel configuration?

I'm trying to get this but didn't found it online

https://www.ddj.co.za/kannel-config/web/index.php?p=configure_group&group=smsc&pp=existing

Comment: opensmppbox can be found under the addons directory of kannel source code. No, there is no a GUI for kannel but it isn't very difficult to make one, as it provides an http listener to start/stop/restart and see the status of current smsc connections

Comment: can you provide a link to how to or to guide me to success the configuration and test if the client can connect to my server as SMPP?